# How to set params for eth_getLogs in order to query ERC721 burn event?

Tags: json-rpc

I want to query this data using curl.
https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tx/0x0819826eb519a33b5d856fd8566a902b7da3e30dd8635c90b75ccf70cf5cac9b#eventlog

I tried this command but get an empty return. Is there something that I'm missing?

```
curl https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/<my-key>\
-X POST \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-d '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_getLogs","params": [{"topics":["0xddf252ad1be2c89b69c2b068fc378daa952ba7f163c4a11628f55a4df523b3ef","0x0000000000000000000000003639f46a7c2060fff60c9020bdcc92055a9af1cc","0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000","0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002"]}],"id":1}'
```

result

```
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":1,"result":[]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
curl https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/<your-key>\
                                -X POST \
                                -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
                                -d '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_getLogs","params": [{"fromBlock":"0x00", "address":"0xf62888ad60570cb396f1324dcc250ce5bad9229a" , "topics":["0xddf252ad1be2c89b69c2b068fc378daa952ba7f163c4a11628f55a4df523b3ef","0x0000000000000000000000003639f46a7c2060fff60c9020bdcc92055a9af1cc","0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000","0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002"]}],"id":1}'
```

#### Explain

See this Infura RPC endpoint documentation

https://infura.io/docs/ethereum/json-rpc/eth-getLogs

> fromBlock [optional, default is "latest"] - an integer block number, or the string "latest", "earliest" or "pending"

You missed "fromBlock" Parameter, so the default latest is set, which means you only taking the latest block info that does not have your target event.

Comment: also note, Infura has query limitation for this RPC endpoint.

>A max of 10,000 results can be returned by a single query